# What are the extra things I can do to earn Sega Miles?

Tags: sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

In Sonic and Sega All Stars Racing, one of the loading screen mentions there are "possibly other things you can do in a race to earn Sega Miles." I know you get more miles if you win races, but what other things can I do to make sure I earn as many Miles as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you only get Sega Miles at the end of a race, and its tied to how well you do in the race.  There's some speculation that the distance travelled is a factor as well.

[People](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing/achievement/36747-Golden-Acts.html) who have been trying to [farm miles](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960423-sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing/53676270) for some of the higher order licenses seem to think that the best way to go is to just run 1-lap races.   However, I'd think that if you're just trying to have fun, it's probably just better to play it however you like.

Comment: on the ipad i farmed one lap races and am now on the gold, didn't take too long either.